# Angular 2: Service injects service, Provider

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service A. That service gets another sevice B injected.
So A uses B. B is used by A and injected in As construcotr.

In a component I use service A. I do not directly use service B. But A uses B because B is injected into A.

In this component I need to put

```
providers: [A, B]
```

If I only put A into providers I get

```
"ERROR: No provider for B"
```

in the Javascript console of the browser. I do not get a compiler error.

Is there a way to hide further services that are not directly used in the components provider?

I do not like to put B into the components provider and not direclty using it.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I can put all services into the module-provider and then I must not set them in any component I use a service. But is there any negative effect when doing so?

Comment: You can provide service B in the module so that you don't have to provide it at each of your components.

Comment: DI provides the providers. Each component and module has its own Injector, if the Injector can't find the provider it asks its parent Injector until the module. Using service B in the service A doesn't mean service B will be provided. Component or module must provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you do not completely understand how DI works in Angular... Please read https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#injector-bubbling

Long story short:

- `@NgModule({providers:[]}) export class AppModule{}` are available in entire application
- `@NgModule({providers:[]}) export class UserModule` are available in all `@Component`s and `@Injectable`s that registered in current module
- `@Component({providers:[]})` are available in this component (and children, but there are some exceptions)
- `@Component({providers:[]})` creates new injector. In practice that means that if you have 3 components on your page, each one has NEW instance of injected service. I.e. in this case you do not share anything between components. That feature is rarely required...
- When `Injector` resolves DI tree it searches for OWN registered `@Injectables`, if nothing is found, then it asks parent. So that means if you have `Service1` that depends on `Service2`, so `Service2` must be provided either in `@Component` or in `@NgModule` and Angular still will be able to resolve DI tree.
- There is no drawbacks from putting all `@Injectable`s into `@NgModule`, moreover that is "Angular way". Having individual `@Component({providers:[]})` in most cases is overkill and in theory should slow your app. So use it only if you really need new instance of Service for each component.